# results changing between loop, manual entry in R

Tags: r, loops, factors

I'm running into a weird issue of looped results being different from manually entered ones. I need to count the number of levels in a set of variables in a data-set. So I wrote a little code that turns the variable into a factor, counts the number of levels and sets this as numeric. This works fine. But when I loop it across all variables, it says each variable has 1 level. 
      This happened on the dataset I'm using and the sample data I created below. It also happened when I wrote a function and used that in apply instead of a for loop. It must be something wrong with the loop, but I'm stuck. 
       Any thoughts?

Here is the sample data, a dataframe with three variables (X,Y,Z), 18 observations.

```
X <- rep(c(1,2,3), 6)
Y <- rep(c(1,2), 9)
Z <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 3)
XYZ_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y,Z))
```

So I count the number of levels for each variable-

```
levelsX <- as.numeric(nlevels(as.factor(XYZ_df$X)))
levelsY <- as.numeric(nlevels(as.factor(XYZ_df$Y)))
levelsZ <- as.numeric(nlevels(as.factor(XYZ_df$Z)))
```

The result is right- levelsX is 3, levelsY is 2 and levelsZ is 6.

But when I loop it, it changes. I created a vector with the values of the variables, then entered it into a for loop, pasting the XYZ_df$ prefix to the loop entry-

```
vars <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
outlist <- list()
for (a in vars) {
  levels <- as.numeric(nlevels(as.factor(paste("XYZ_df$",a, sep=""))))
  out <- c(a, levels)
  outlist <- c(outlist, list(out))
}

final <- do.call("rbind", outlist)
```

When I do this, the levels entry for each variable is 1.

As I said, this happened with two datasets, so I know it's my code. It happened with the apply as well. And it happened both the way I did it above (pasting the XYZ_df to the variable name) and when I used attach(XYZ_df) and just entered the variable name.

Comment: How many factor do you expect `factor("XYZ_dfX")` to have? You transform a character vector of length 1 to a factor. I'm not sure why you expected a different result than what you got.

Comment: that was an error in my code, left out the $, it's fixed now. But it still comes up even if I loop across separate objects, not in the dataframe-   vars <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
outlist <- list()
for (a in vars) {
  levels <- as.numeric(nlevels(as.factor(a)))
  out <<- c(a, levels)
  outlist <- c(outlist, list(out))
}

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Possibly you want `factor(XYZ_df[, a])`. `$` is special, because it uses non-standard evaluation and thus it can't be used for this. You might benefit from reading `help("[")`.

Comment: ok, that did it, thanks. XYZ_df$data worked outside the loop, but I guess the brackets are the better way to go with this

Comment: `XYZ_df$data` is **not** the same as `"XYZ_df$data"`.